# using requestAnimationFrame and DOMContentLoaded for deferring assets

Tags: javascript, css, performance, load

I've taken the following snippet from [googles Optimize CSS Delivery page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery),

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
    <script>
      var cb = function() {
        var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
        l.href = 'small.css';
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(cb);
      else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In most domready scripts, if `window.addEventListener` is supported then the scripts attempts "DOMContentLoaded" first.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cb, false);
window.addEventListener("load", cb, false);
```

but this script doesn't, why is this? when using this script for loading deferred CSS, could i use my [domready](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-domReady/2.0.1/domReady.js) function as a fallback instead?

```
if (raf) raf(cb);
      else domready(cb);
```

When loading deferred JS I use domready rather than the `defer` attribute as I know it will work in all browsers.

Should or could requestAnimationFrame ever be used to load other assets such as js or images to improve the initial page load time?

One problem with using domready to load scripts/ styles is that the download also gets deferred rather than just the execution/render.

Providing any links to what you believe is the best way to load different assets would be very helpful to myself and others.